# Form Tag inherits P tag alignment

Tags: html

Is there a way for a form tag to inherit alignment from a p tag directly above it?

Example:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<form...
```

By default, it aligns left. However I am curious if there is a way as the img tag does inherit the alignment:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<img...
```

Edit: Fiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/nyqyxczh/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of the problem?

Comment: Sure, https://jsfiddle.net/nyqyxczh/

Answer (score 2):

A `form` is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), which means it doesn't pay attention to `text-align`. If you set your `form` to `display: inline-block`, you might be able to get it to observe the `p` tag's alignment.

On a stylistic note, though: I'd recommend against putting `form` tags inside `p` tags, as that's not really a paragraph of text, is it? Unless you're trying for an inline-style `form`: "Hello, my name is _______ and my email is ______." In which case yeah, definitely go with `display: inline` but I'd probably put the `p` inside the `form`.

### Edit 2 to clarify the above:

A block-level element will inherit the properties of its parent like any other (see below re: why the `form` will not inherit `p` styles), but the block itself will not align according to `text-align` because `text-align` defines the alignment of inline things. That is, a `div` inside a `text-center` `div` will not be centered, itself, unless it is marked as `inline-block` or `inline`. But the inner `div`'s contents will be centered within that inner `div`.

### Edit

It looks like `form` isn't a valid child of `p` and thus will be forced out of the `p` by the browser, thereby not inheriting any styling (or recognizing selectors like `p > form`). So the answer is that you can't get `form` to inherit stuff from `p` because it refuses to nest within `p`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried display: inline-block but it does not work. As a side note, the reason why I am asking this question is due to a WordPress plugin I am developing. The default text editor in WordPress uses the p tag for alignment so I don't have any control over that part unfortunately. I can easily solve my problem by requiring the user to separately specify alignment and pass that to a div. But I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the `form` to align center or the text within it?

Comment: The text and elements within it.

Comment: @scottpaterson At least in Chrome, it looks like the browser rejects `form` as a child of `p` and moves it outside the `p`, so it doesn't inherit anything. See [here](http://codepen.io/bensaufley/pen/yNLejZ?editors=110) and inspect element. I've assigned a color of red to `p > form`, and yet that's not getting applied, because Chrome does not accept that `form` is a child of `p`. That is likely your problem.

Comment: I'd suggest the WordPress plugin (are you creating a shortcode?) take alignment or class as a parameter (eg `[plugin-form align="right"]`) and apply that to the form itself.

Comment: I agree. I noticed that also in FF. If you view the source you see the p tag above and below the form like normal, but if you use the browser inspector it shows a p open and close tag above the form and the same below the form.

Comment: Yes, I am using shortcodes. And that is a solution but the user would have to add that manually. It is not passed from the editor, right? Or is their a way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "passed from the editor." In my experience with shortcodes, my above example is how it's done. You add [shortcode] where you want it, and any parameters you'd like to add would be included there. If they want to align center, they'd have to specify that with an attribute.

Comment: What I mean by "passed from the editor" was, I thought maybe you meant there was a way that the plugin could hook into the WordPress editor. So that when a user had entered a shortcode and pressed the "align center" button" the center attribute would be added inside the shortcode automatically instead of the user having to manually type it.

Comment: Ah. Nope, not to my knowledge. Shortcodes are convenient for non-devs but still require a little bit of typing.

Answer (score -2):

```
Inheritance concerns,

transferring information from a style sheet to the elements of a web document.

Declarations are defined into CSS rules, concern specific HTML elements, which are known as selectors. Elements that are embedded (inline) into selectors-elements for whom the style has been declared through a CSS rule automatically get the same style.

In our example below, the paragraph element <p> contains elements that inherit its style properties.

The CSS rule for the paragraph element <p> is:     


  p  {font family: arial, san-serif;  color: blue}


We then write the HTML code as below:


 <p>Inheritance concerns
   <b>the information transition
      <i>from a style sheet</i>           
   </b>
   to the elements of a web document 
</p>


which gives us







The inner elements b and i give their contents the style of parent element p. This means that they inherit the style from their outer element which is the tag <p>.

Most of the CSS properties are inherited from the parent to its child elements.

This fact gives us the possibility when we design our CSS style sheet to start from the top level elements in the hierarchic structure of HTML document and pass the style properties to the embedded elements (inner) avoiding to rewrite them for these elements.

Properties which are not inherited such as display, vertical-align and the border properties if we do not define a declaration through a style rule that sets values to them, they will take the default values of the browser when it reads the web document.
```

Comment: This is not really an answer is it?

Comment: I understand all about CSS and alignment. There is not my question. I don't want to add css to my form tag.... My question is, is this possible for a form tag to inherit alignment from a p tag?